# Stray Checkbox Checked and Unchecked Events for Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have a ListBox ItemTemplate where I have a CheckBox that is Binded to a List<> that I am maintaining in my application.

My XAML:

```
  <ListBox x:Name ="lstTasks">
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="30,12,0,0">
                         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding use}" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" Tag="{Binding key}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" />
                         <TextBlock Width="160" Text="{Binding key}" Margin="20,18,0,0" />
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding value}"  Margin="0,18,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

And :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    lstTasks.ItemsSource = null;
    lstTasks.ItemsSource = a.Words; //a.Words is the List<DataClass>
}
```

I have observed that the Checked and Unchecked events get fired on its own when I scroll in the list of these Items. I have logic attached to these Events and they mess the whole thing up by checking and unchecking random entries. This starts after I uncheck one of the items. (By default all the items are checked)

I am new to WPF and Windows Phone, what am I doing wrong.?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Windows Phone does not use WPF. You are using Silverlight which is based on a sub-set of WPF. They are different technologies with different capabilities. Much of what you can do on one you can't do on the other.

It would help to see more of your code, particularly the viewmodel to get a complete picture of what's going on.

I suspect one of two things though:
1 - there is some logic somewhere based on the setting of the `use` property and as this is changed in the vm, the fact it is reflected in the UI and that triggers the events.
2 - You have a virtualized list inside your ListBox and as items are loaded it's triggering the UI updates (due to the binding) and that in turn is triggering the events.

Without being able to see more code it's hard to be more specific.

As an alternative to this approach you could use a 2-way binding of the `use` property and move the logic from your event handlers (for checked and unchecked) and into the property setter.

Comment: I haven't used MVVM or any such thing. I am directly using ItemsSources and assigning that to my custom object. Your point 2. is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: @ShadowClaw by using Bindings there is an argument that you are using MVVM. If point 2 is what you're doing then simply replace the virtualising stackpanel with one that doesn't virtualize. With just a single line of XAML and a description of your code it's hard to provide specific advise on how to resolve your issue.

Comment: I have put the code. 'CheckBox_Unchecked' and 'CheckBox_Checked' are the stray events that are getting fired. I have probably broken quite a lot of rules in my code I guess!

Comment: @ShadowClaw where have you put the code? A repro of your scenario will likley be necessary to provide dircet further advice.

Comment: I just edited my post to add the complete XAML code. I just haven't added the event methods. They do change a.Words from my code. Can that be a problem? Would you also see those methods? They are getting called while scrolling the list, that's the problems, not the code itself.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ShadowClaw a suitable repro will be a complete example which includes the minimum amount of code to recreate the issue you're seeing.